# How to emulate file as USB device to be attached to virtual machine in linux?

Tags: stream, pipe, vmware, emulation

I have a video stream of Desktop which is piped from Webcam Studio to /dev/video2 and a Windows 7 virtual machine that is running on Vmware. How can I emulate or attach the stream without a networking technique to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which is located in here in details:
http://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/USB_Gadget_Mass_Storage